# awaitQuiescence does not return after timeout

Tags: java, concurrency, forkjoinpool

I'm trying to use the awaitQuiescence method from ForkJoinPool to wait until all submitted tasks are finished, or return false if the tasks are not yet completed after the timeout.

Practically all of submitted tasks can add additional tasks to the pool, so I can't use the awaitTermination method, because that would block those additional tasks from being submitted.
However, the awaitQuiescence does not return anything, even when the specified time is over.

I tried to crystallize the issue in the code below. The CountDownLatch.await will never be triggered, but why does the awaitQuiescence method not return false?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final ForkJoinPool test = new ForkJoinPool(1,
            ForkJoinPool.defaultForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory, null,true);
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    test.execute(() -> { 
            try {
                System.out.println("Sleeping");
                Future<Double> f = test.submit(() -> { 
                        latch.await(); 
                        return 0d; 
                    });
                System.out.println(f.get());
                System.out.println("Waking up");
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            });

    System.out.println(test.awaitQuiescence(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
}
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: The lambda for execute is not a functional interface and does not compile. There is no latch.countDown() so the latch.await() will  never exit. Rather than doing this in the main thread, you need another thread to submit the test... and so much more.

Answer (score 1):

> why does the awaitQuiescence method not return false?

It seems that `awaitQuiescence` ignores `timeout` while there are pending tasks and executes the tasks in the caller's thread (see [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.java#3155)).

Thread dump:

```
"ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1" [...] Object.wait() [...]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
  [...]
  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.get(ForkJoinTask.java:995)
  [...]
  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)

[...]

"main" [...] waiting on condition [...]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
  [...]
  at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:231)
  [...]
  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1445)
  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.awaitQuiescence(ForkJoinPool.java:3097)
  [...]
```

"main" thread executes second task and waits for the latch, hence `awaitQuiescence` never terminates.

In my opinion this is a bug. Based on the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#awaitQuiescence-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) I'd assume that the max running time of the method ("the maximum time to wait") is approximately `timeout`, but upper bound is actually more like the time of execution of all pending tasks and all of their "descendants" (possibly except the terminal ones).

On the other hand FJ pool is not quite intended for this type of tasks (with non-pool-managed synchronization). From the ForkJoinTask's [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html):

> Computations should ideally avoid synchronized methods or blocks, and
>   should minimize other blocking synchronization apart from joining
>   other tasks or using synchronizers such as Phasers that are advertised
>   to cooperate with fork/join scheduling.

[...]

> It is possible to define and use ForkJoinTasks that may block, but
>   doing do requires three further considerations: (1) Completion of few
>   if any other tasks should be dependent on a task that blocks on
>   external synchronization or I/O. Event-style async tasks that are
>   never joined (for example, those subclassing CountedCompleter) often
>   fall into this category. (2) To minimize resource impact, tasks should
>   be small; ideally performing only the (possibly) blocking action. (3)
>   Unless the ForkJoinPool.ManagedBlocker API is used, or the number of
>   possibly blocked tasks is known to be less than the pool's
>   ForkJoinPool.getParallelism() level, the pool cannot guarantee that
>   enough threads will be available to ensure progress or good
>   performance.

Consider using `ThreadPoolExecutor` and/or emulating `awaitQuiescence` (e.g. using [Phaser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html)). Sketch of the possible implementation:

```
class TaskTrackingExecutorService implements ExecutorService {

  private final ExecutorService delegate;
  private final Phaser taskTracker = new Phaser();

  public TaskTrackingExecutorService(ExecutorService delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
  }

  @Override
  public <T> Future<T> submit(Callable<T> task) {
    return delegate.submit(() -> {
      taskTracker.register();
      try {
        return task.call();
      } finally {
        taskTracker.arriveAndDeregister();
      }
    });
  }

  @Override
  public void execute(Runnable command) {
    submit(Executors.callable(command));
  }

  public boolean awaitQuiescence(long timeout, TimeUnit timeUnit) throws InterruptedException {
    taskTracker.register();
    try {
      taskTracker.awaitAdvanceInterruptibly(taskTracker.arriveAndDeregister(), timeout, timeUnit);
      return true;
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean awaitTermination(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
    return delegate.awaitTermination(timeout, unit);
  }

  // rest is similar: either use submit method or the delegate.

}


public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    TaskTrackingExecutorService pool =
        new TaskTrackingExecutorService(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    pool.execute(() -> {
          System.out.println("Sleeping");
          Future<Double> f = pool.submit(() -> {
            latch.await();
            return 0d;
          });
          try {
            System.out.println(f.get());
          } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
          System.out.println("Waking up");
        }
    );

    System.out.println(pool.awaitQuiescence(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
  }
}
```